# Hadoop startup error "unrecognized option jvm could not start a virtual machine"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am facing this error after the command
sudo $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh
I have read the discussion on stackoverflow on this and they all refer to it a bug.
I am trying to implement the HDGs-1943.patch but getting the following error

```
sudo patch -p0 < /path/HDFS-1943.patch $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop
hunk  #1 Failed at 71
```

please help

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: 0.20.203 and 0.20.204 both are giving these errors

Comment: Why are you staying with hadoop version 0.20, because hadoop stable higher version are available 1.X and 2.X if you use any of that versions this would be solved.

Comment: Ok now I am using 1.2.1 version and am able to successfully execute sudo bin/start-all.sh it prompts me for password for 3 times but shows no error. Afterwards when i run jps, no daemons is shown.

Comment: when i do sudo jps, there i can see all the hadoop daemons running successfully but still in root mode also i cannot exeute fs -ls command